# checkarray: E: MD subsystem not loaded, or /proc unavailable

Tags: debian

I have debian squeeze webserver and each week I receive an email with error:

**Subject**: Cron  if [ -x /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray ] && [ $(date +%d) -le 7 ]; then /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray --cron --all --idle --quiet; fi (failed)

**Mail**: checkarray: E: MD subsystem not loaded, or /proc unavailable.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

I found this although what is it I need to remove?
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=616688

Comment: I have just checked all of my crons and cant find anywhere "mdadm" is mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have the mdadm package installed, but no md arrays (software RAID arrays) configured.

The mdadm crontab script is in /etc/cron.d/mdadm

If you remove the mdadm package, it will stop the error occuring.